# how to redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, redirect

This is my javascript function and I want to redirect to another page on success of this event so how can I do it?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure you want to go back?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure you want to go back?';
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this

```
window.location.href = 'http://redirecttourl.com'
```

Comment: okay I got this. onbeforeunload will only ask for yes/no. Anything in this will not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your location :

```
window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
```

Comment: Try on a web page : go on `google.com`, open the developer console and run the command in my answer. It works !