# window.location returns different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, window.location, contentplaceholder

I have a problem: https://ibb.co/ccx5c7

```
var _yolcuSayisiYetiskin = $("#slcYolcuYetiskin").text();
var _yolcuSayisiCocuk = $("#slcYolcuCocuk").text();
var _yolcuSayisiBebek = $("#slcYolcuBebek").text();
var _gidisOriginCode = $('#inpNeredenAirportCode').val();
var _gidisDestinationCode = $('#inpNereyeAirportCode').val();
var dateGidisTarihi = $("#departure_date").val();

if (dateGidisTarihi.match(/[a-zA-Z\s]/g)) {
    return false;
}
else {
    if (dateGidisTarihi.length > 0) {
        $("#departure_date").css("color", "#000");
    }
    else {
        $("#departure_date").css("color", "#d14300");
        $("#departure_date").val("Bu alan boş geçilemez!");
        return false;
    }
}

var _gidisTarih = dateGidisTarihi; // After
var _donusTarih = $("#return_date").val();
var _ucusTipi = $("#orUcusTipiTekYon").prop('checked') ? "OW" : "RT";
var requestPath = "/Ucus/Seferler.aspx?gdOriginCode=" + _gidisOriginCode
    + "&gdDestinationCode=" + _gidisDestinationCode
    + "&gTarih=" + _gidisTarih
    + "&dTarih=" + _donusTarih
    + "&ysYetiskin=" + _yolcuSayisiYetiskin
    + "&ysCocuk=" + _yolcuSayisiCocuk
    + "&ysBebek=" + _yolcuSayisiBebek;

window.location = requestPath;
```

The `requestPath` is `/Ucus/Seferler.aspx?gdOriginCode=ADATR&gdDestinationCode=IST&gTarih=30.03.2018&dTarih=&ysYetiskin=1&ysCocuk=0&ysBebek=0`

But `window.location` returns `http://localhost:1374/Ucus/Seferler.aspx?ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNereden=Adana+-+T%C3%BCrkiye%28Sakirpasa-ADA%29&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNeredenAirportCode=ADATR&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNeredenCountryCode=TR&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNeredenCountryName=T%C3%BCrkiye&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNeredenCityName=Adana&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNereye=%C4%B0stanbul+-+T%C3%BCrkiye%28Ataturk-IST%29&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNereyeAirportCode=IST&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNereyeCountryCode=TR&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24inpNereyeCityName=Istanbul&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24departure_date=30.03.2018&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24return_date=`

Comment: I find it really hard to understand what the problem is!

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Add some explanation to the problem.

Comment: try [window.location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972541/how-to-redirect-to-another-page/42972838#42972838) instead of `window.location`

Comment: You realize that `localhost` means `this computer`, so no one except you can view that link :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to redirect to `requestPath`. If you want to do that, you must use: `location.href = requestPath`

Comment: Nope, you can, but you dont have to. `location` is a very special object